# Update multiple rows in table based on conditions from another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, multi-table

Just demo. I have two table

```
Table a (id, name)
--id---name----
  1    John
  2    Jack
  3    Maria
  4    Bill
Table b (id, empid, datewrk)
--id---empid----datewrk----
  1      1    2012-12-12
  2      2    2012-12-14
  3      3    2012-12-16
  4      4    2012-12-17
```

I want update all name = null in table a where date in table b <= '2012-12-14', the result is

```
--id---name--
  1   NULL
  2   NULL
```

I have try code bellow but no work (only work with SELECT statement). I try in MySql Workbench and SQL Server 2012

```
UPDATE a
SET name = NUll
WHERE id IN (SELECT a.id FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.id = b.empid 
WHERE b.datewrk <= '2012-12-14');
```

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mysql

```
UPDATE a 
JOIN b ON a.id = b.empid 
SET a.name = NUll
WHERE b.datewrk <= '2012-12-14';
```

You don't need a subquery just join your table put set clause in right place then where clause

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2f7e/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your Update Statement should work, but in order to compare you have to convert `'2012-12-14'` to date.

```
UPDATE a
SET name = NULL
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT empid FROM b 
   WHERE datewrk <= STR_TO_DATE('2012-12-14', '%Y-%m-%d'));
```

Note that in your subquery you don't need table `A`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank, your tip is very helpful.
Try and work in sqlfiddle but nothing happen in mysql workbend, maybe problem in tool :D

Comment: Don't think there is a problem in tool. You simply have to remove the join from the subquery. It does not make sense to join a table in a subquery, which you want to update with the main query/statement.